# WCF returns ArrayOfKeyValueOfintstringKeyValueOfintstring[] instead of Dictionary<int, string> and Array instread of List

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, collections, client-server

So I've spent the last several hours investigating this issue and it is clear that I am not the only one. Why are my Dictionaries and Lists being returned as Arrays?

I understand that Arrays are used as default for the sake of compatibility. WCF makes a conscious effort to distance itself from being .Net dependent. But both my Server and Client are developed in C# .Net so I'm okay.

Here is a sampling of similar questions on just StackOverflow alone:

1. [WCF service returning array instead of List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551541/wcf-service-returning-array-instead-of-list)
2. [Why does WCF return myObject[] instead of List like I was
   expecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493376/why-does-wcf-return-myobject-instead-of-listt-like-i-was-expecting)
3. [WCF service returning an array of dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160052/wcf-service-returning-an-array-of-dictionarystring-object)
4. [WCF Proxy Returning Array instead of List EVEN THOUGH Collection
   Type == Generic.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513027/wcf-proxy-returning-array-instead-of-list-even-though-collection-type-generic)
5. [WCF Returning Array instead of List EVEN THOUGH Collection Type ==
   Generic.List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298066/wcf-returning-array-instead-of-list-even-though-collection-type-generic-list)
6. [Why does my WCF service return and ARRAY instead of a List ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525463/why-does-my-wcf-service-return-and-array-instead-of-a-list-t)
7. [Array instead of List in WCF Service Proxy Generated using
   svcutil.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101245/array-instead-of-list-in-wcf-service-proxy-generated-using-svcutil-exe)

**What I have set up:**
[image: Service Reference Configuration]

I am generating the Proxy via this command:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin>svcutil.exe /language:cs
 /out:generatedProxy.cs /config:app.config /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1
  http://192.168.0.99:9000/ProjectDatabase/??
```

My service contract looks like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(Dictionary<int, string>))]
    Dictionary<int, string> getClassDictionary();
}
```

My implementation:

```
public Dictionary <int, string> getClassDictionary()
{
   Dictionary<int, string> myDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
   myDict.Add(1, "Geometry");
   myDict.Add(2, "Algebra");
   myDict.Add(3, "Graph Theory");
   return myDict; 
}
```

Even in my `Reference.svcmap` I have:

```
<CollectionMappings>
  <CollectionMapping TypeName="System.Collections.Generic.List`1" Category="List" />
</CollectionMappings>
```

However, despite my best efforts and research I still get:

> Dictionary<'int, string'> returning as ArrayOfKeyValueOfintstringKeyValueOfintstring[]

And:

> List<'T'> returning as T[]

I feel like I've tried everything and done everything right, but I have to be missing something. So what is it? Thank you for your time, help, and consideration.

**Update:**

I've even attempted a route of working around the `Array` imposition, by writing a `serializable` `struct` and adding them to an array.

```
[Serializable]
public struct KeyValuePair<K, V>
{
    public K Key { get; set; }
    public V Value { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I return the `KeyValuePair<int, string>[]`. My proxy is generating a return of `KeyValuePairOfintstring[]`.

**Solution is posted below.**

Comment: I loved this `ArrayOfKeyValueOfintstringKeyValueOfintstring[]`

Comment: Why would the proxy be generated like that?

Comment: Strange. I just built a new service, host, and client that returns a `Dictionary<int, string>` and it works just fine. Tomorrow I'll write up a new solution and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found out what was causing the serialization to be so crude.

In my `ServiceContract` I had the following:

```
[OperationContract]
List<DataTable> ShowTables();
[OperationContract]
DataTable FetchContacts(string filter = "All");
[OperationContract]
DataTable FetchUsers();
[OperationContract]
DataTable FetchDrops();
```

After commenting this out and recompiling my WCF Service Library, I found that everything serialized/ deserialized appropriately when generating the proxy.

It seems that when `svcutil.exe` encounters something that it does not know how to serialize then all bets are off. Quite literally it will ignore your commands/settings and serialize everything as gibberish like `ArrayOfKeyValueOfinttringKeyValueOfintstring`. So if you receive this error, you should ask yourself if `svcutil.exe` is able to properly serialize all of what you are returning.

I hope the identification of the source of my issue will help others in the future.

Comment: Hope someone from Microsoft can say something about this. It is taking up too much of many people's time.

Comment: is there a good way to figure out what it doesn't know how to serialize?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way I currently know how to determine the ability to serialize a given type is to use **svcutil** and take a look at the generated proxy - then process of elimination of types until I remove one that causes the outputted proxy to look the way it should. If I needed a given type and svcutil was spitting out garbage when I was using it - I would just write my own serializable type with the functionality that I needed.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to debug/diagnose svcutil?

Comment: I feel like I'm stuck in the same spot but I can't figure out what to change/comment out as I don't have a block of code like that in my ServiceContract ... but I am being tortured by my Lists turning into ArrayOfGibberish[] nonsense! Dear God please help ...

Comment: Had this happen on a small service with about 20 OperationContracts. All passed POCOs except for one, which used a DataTable. Everything turned into array until I commented out the operation that used DataTable. Solution: create an object to represent the data previously passed in DataTable and use that instead.